# session doesn't work in background process PHP file with symfony 2.0

Tags: php, symfony, session

I am sending email in background process. For background process I am using symfony 2.0. Background works successfully. but in background I can't get session value.. Below code of index.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['album_upload'] = {"a","b"};
$command = file_get_contents('background.php');
$process = new PhpProcess($command);
$process->run();
```

below code of background.php

```
session_start();
$message = $_SESSION['album_upload'][0];
mail("webmaster@example.com","example",$message,"From: $from\n"); // Session doesn't give any value.
```

If I remove session and just try to send mail like `mail("webmaster@example.com","example","example","From: $from\n");` then mail will send.

How to get the session value in background.php.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_php_bridge.html

Comment: Session data is retrived based on the sessio id cookie the browser sends with the request. A background task isnt initiated by a browser, so no cookie, so no session data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to retrieve the session id from you're first script and pass it to the next one.
You can do it with the [session_id() func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

Code Index.php

```
$session_id = session_id();
new PhpProcess($command, null, array('session_id' => $session_id));
$process->start();
while ($process->isRunning()) {// waiting for process to finish }
```

Code background.php

```
session_id($_SERVER['session_id']);
session_start();
$message = $_SESSION['album_upload'][0];
mail("webmaster@example.com","example",$message,"From: $from\n"); // Session doesn't give any value.
```

Comment: @issac I never used `session_id()` before. But how to set in index.php and get it in background.php so I can get my ` $_SESSION['album_upload']` data

Comment: @ Issac Your code working now. I don't know but $process->run(); waits for the execution and after run it will execute rest of code.?? I want to execute in background. It should not be wait for execution. It is possible???

Comment: @user3730347 put $process-start() to execute in background, then add this at the end of you're code `while ($process->isRunning()) {
    // waiting for process to finish
} ` to be sure that your email got the necessary time to be sent.

Answer (score 2):

PhpProcess runs as a seperate php process; this means it does not have access to the $_SESSION information that was available to the original request to your server.

You can pass the data as follows:

```
new PhpProcess($command, null, array('album_upload' => $_SESSION['album_upload'][0]));
```

That should allow you to acccess the data in your background script as the variable:

```
$_SERVER['album_upload']
```

Comment: when I an using `print_r($_SERVER['album_upload'])` at background it gives me **1** output. I need to set two-dimensional array

Comment: I'd guess you need to double check the structure of your $_SESSION['album_upload'] variable.

Comment: Is PhpProcess() doing background process??. means we don't need to do like `ini_set('max_execution_time', 500)` for execution time???

Comment: I don't know but `$process->run();` waits for the execution and after run it will execute rest of code.?? I want to execute in background. It should not be wait for execution. It is possible???

Comment: `$process->start()` will run the code in the background without blocking. However, Symfony automatically stops child process when its main thread completes, so your email may not be sent.

Comment: I used it. but it doesn't run background process.

Comment: As I said, it may not run depending on how long your main thread takes to complete. If you're having problems with that, ask another question to get more people seeing the problem. Include your full code listing.